# Issue with variables scope in Js/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, requirejs

Having issue with - what I supposed to be - basics scope fundamentals.
I am using Javascript with Require JS structure, here are where the issue occurs:

```
function GameManager() {
    //This is the constructor of gamemanager.js file
    this.body = $('body');
    this.game = $('#game');
}

GameManager.prototype.createGame = function() {

    //Code

    //this line works
    this.body.append(//Some HTML);
}

GameManager.prototype.showGame = function() {
    //Code

    //this line does not work wtf
    this.game.removeClass("display-none");
    //and this one does work.
    $("#game").removeClass("display-none");
}
```

I am using this.body succefully so I want to use the same way for this.game but it doesnt work. I can manage to make it work by using directly $("#game") but it's making jquery running through the DOM everytime so not really optimized...

I certainly am missing some basics points here, can someone explain ?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you create object for `GameManager`?

Comment: Not sure to understand the question. I am not using objects there.

Comment: Ok, where did you use this snippet? `var something = new GameManager();`

Comment: @GreatHawkeye I think he asked that to make sure that you create the GameManager after the `DOM` is loaded.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I am creating the instance in my main.js file in his init() function. That is the very first function that I use !

Comment: @GreatHawkeye Are you sure that you are calling `init()` it inside of DOM ready handler?

Comment: are you using document.ready(function(){...})? Your class should be instantiated inside there.

Comment: I am using it like this :
        function init(){
        var gamemanager = new GameManager();
    }

    $(init);

And it works to initiate the init function

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. I can remove display-none class from div without a problem. It wont display however. You need to change css. this.body.css("display","block"); for example.

```
window.onload = function() {

function GameManager() {
    //This is the constructor of gamemanager.js file
    this.body = $('body');
    this.game = $('#game');
}

GameManager.prototype.createGame = function() {

    //Code

    //this line works
    this.body.append();
}

GameManager.prototype.showGame = function() {
    //Code

    this.body.css("display", "block");
    //this line does not work wtf
    this.game.removeClass("display-none");
    //and this one does work.
    //$("#game").removeClass("display-none");
}


var myGame = new GameManager();
myGame.showGame();
}
```